# Asp .Net Gridview paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Trying paging of a grid.

```
  <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="paging"/>
          <PagerTemplate>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left; width:50%">

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrv" Visible="false" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server">Previous</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:50%;padding-left:50%;">                        
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNext" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server">Next</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </PagerTemplate>
```

Code behind is below

```
    protected void gvProduct_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal1.Visible = gvProduct.PageIndex == 0;

        LinkButton lnkPrv = (LinkButton)gvProduct.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("lnkPrv");
        LinkButton lnkNext = (LinkButton)gvProduct.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("lnkNext");

        lnkPrv.Visible = e.NewPageIndex > 0;
        lnkNext.Visible = e.NewPageIndex < gvProduct.PageCount - 1;
        gvProduct.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        FillGrid();
    }
```

The code does not give any error. I can see it set the visible property to true/false.
But actual control on page remain same (always visible on every page). '

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code for your FillGrid method?

Comment: Do any of the answers help? If so, can you mark this question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your FillGrid() method is rebinding gvProduct (i.e. gvProduct.DataBind()) then lnkPrv and lnkNext Visible values are going to use their defaults from the markup when databinding.  You need to set the visibility of these controls in an event handler for RowDataBound event of gvProduct.

```
protected void gvProduct_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
            Literal1.Visible = gvProduct.PageIndex == 0;
            gvProduct.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            FillGrid();
}

protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager) {
      LinkButton lnkPrv = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkPrv");
      LinkButton lnkNext = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkNext");
      lnkPrv.Visible = gvProduct.PageIndex > 0;
      lnkNext.Visible = gvProduct.PageIndex < gvProduct.PageCount - 1;
     }
}
```